# Compile Inno Setup installer for specific component only

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script that creates an installer (`FullInstall.exe`, for example).  The script contains several components, selected using types in the standard way, so that it currently has something like:

```
[Types]
Name: standard; Description: Standard installation
Name: dev; Description: Development installation
Name: disponly; Description: Display utility only
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: core; Description: Core files; Types: standard dev display custom; Flags: fixed
Name: exec; Description: Executive; Types: standard dev custom
Name: exec\debug; Description: Debugger; Types: dev custom
Name: display; Description: Display utility; Types: dev disponly custom
```

What I've been asked to do is to create an installer for the display utility only. I could create a batch file (`DispInstall.bat`) which just contained:

```
FullInstall /COMPONENTS="core,display"
```

However, this method requires a copy of `FullInstall.exe` in the same directory as `DispInstall.bat`, which isn't ideal.  Is there a method of creating a `DispInstall.exe` file which behaves like `FullInstall.exe` with the `disponly` type selected, and without the user being able to change the type or component selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to filter the `.iss` script to a desired subset only:

```
[Types]
#ifndef disponly
Name: standard; Description: Standard installation
Name: dev; Description: Development installation
#endif
Name: disponly; Description: Display utility only
#ifndef disponly
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom
#endif

[Components]
#ifndef disponly
Name: core; Description: Core files; Types: standard dev display custom; Flags: fixed
Name: exec; Description: Executive; Types: standard dev custom
Name: exec\debug; Description: Debugger; Types: dev custom
#endif
Name: display; Description: Display utility; Types: dev disponly custom
```

And filter everything else that refers to the filtered types and components, the same way.

---

And then run Inno Setup compiler with [`/Ddisponly` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc) to compile the subset version.

---

Or if you use Inno Setup GUI for the compilation, you can create `disponly.iss` like:

```
#define disponly
#include "FullInstall.iss"
```