# Inno Setup preprocessor: Conditionally activate a #define (e.g. only when a certain Registry value is set)

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Normally I build my installers on my "normal" PC in the office, and the EXEs are then stored on the company NAS.

Now (Corona, homeoffice) I modified the installer scripts. I added a `#define NoNetwork`, so the office-network is not needed.

At the moment I need to active the define when I build the installer at home and comment it out when I build the installer in the office.

Is there a way to activate a define only when on the machine where the installer is compiled/created a certain registry key is set (or a special file exists, or....)
So that I don't have to modify the install script every time I switch from home to office?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test for a file existence, use [`#ifexist` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef):

```
#ifexist "C:\some\path\NoNetwork"
#define NoNetwork
#endif
```

---

To test for a registry value, use of [`#if` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if) and [`ReadReg` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=readreg):

```
#if ReadReg(HKCU, "Registry\Key", "NoNetwork", 0) == 1
#define NoNetwork
#endif
```

---

Though if you are using some build script, you should use command-line options to customize the build, like:

```
iscc -DNoNetwork Example1.iss
```

See also [How do I build two different installers from the same script in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034747/850848)